# Fancybox close button does not show

Tags: jquery, fancybox, partial-views

I'm opening a partial view with `fancybox` 2.1.4 but I cant get the closing cross to show.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

The box with the content does show:

```
 function LaunchFancyBox(code) {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'modal': true,
        'closeBtn': true,
        'content': code
    });
}

$('.sendSms').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Sms")',
        success: function (partial) {
            LaunchFancyBox(partial);
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs):

> modal     If set to true, will disable navigation and closing
>   
>   Boolean; Default value: false

Do not set the modal parameter to true

Answer (score 1):

```
closeBtn: 'true',
afterShow: function () {
   $('.fancybox-close').attr('id', 'fancybox-close');
}
```

css

```
#fancybox-close {
display:inline !important;
top: -7px !important;
right: 1px !important;
width: 28px !important;
height: 30px !important;

}
```

And add "fancybox.png" to the same directory of "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"

Download From Here http://www.imagemagick.org/fancybox/fancybox.png

Answer (score -2):

The code you are using looks correct. Make sure you have uploaded the fancybox_sprite.png to wherever you have the main fancybox javascript and css files located, ie. in same folder.

Comment: These last 2 comments by Jizbo and Christoph - and countless other comments re fancybox reminded me what a great support stackoverflow is - in my elusive quest to enlarge a thumbnail (that enlarges a 2nd image, stays within page and has a close button). I would fiddle, but just follow the above thread. For any one looking for the same, my advice is to check, check and recheck.